# Pig RegEx : How to extract year from string pattern

Tags: regex, apache-pig

How to extract a year from string pattern  given as "string (YYYY)" using Pig Latin RegEx function ? 
e.g- 
The Beatles : Eight Days a week - The Touring Year (2016) 
output should be 2016.

Note : String pattern may contain alphabets,special Symbols etc.

Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Your question doesn't indicate any kind of effort on your part.

Answer (score 0):

Match everything `.*` between the two parentheses `\(` and `\)`.Note that this will work only if the strings are in the format of the example string you have given.

```
(?<=\()(.*)(?=\))
```

[Example](https://regexr.com/3tnht)